# Hebrew text parsing using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing, hebrew

I am trying to parse a Hebrew text, but I am not getting any success. Can anyone here please help ?

```
    String hebrewSearhString  = "חן";

    //String regexHebrewPattern = "([\\u0591-\\u05F4\\s]+)"; // Tried this too, but same no success
    String regexHebrewPattern = "([\\p{InHebrew}]+)"; 

    Pattern patternHebrew = Pattern.compile(regexHebrewPattern, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher matcherHebrew = pattern.matcher(hebrewSearhString);

    if(matcherHebrew.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Whole -"+ matcherHebrew.group(0));
        //System.out.println("Group 1 -"+ matcherHebrew.group(1));
        //System.out.println("Group 2 -"+ matcherHebrew.group(2));
    }

    Result : "If" condition doesn't gets to TRUE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This,

```
Matcher matcherHebrew = pattern.matcher(hebrewSearhString);
```

Should be

```
Matcher matcherHebrew = patternHebrew.matcher(hebrewSearhString);
```

And I get the output,

```
Whole -חן
```

Because the `if` does evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Thanks @Elliot. That was a silly mistake. I was using 'pattern' variable for some other purpose above this code.